# Is it possible to filter out the data examined by STL multiset lower_bound using a comparator function?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++, stl

We are using a std::multiset ranges_type member variable to store our Range data. When we call

```
std::multiset<Range>::const_iterator iter = ranges_type.lower_bound(Range(n));
if (iter == ranges_type.end() || iter->low() > n){     
    found = false;
}
else{
    curr = *(iter);
}
```

There are multiple candidate Range elements that  `ranges_type.lower_bound(Range(n))` could return. However, STL `multiset::lower_bound(Range(n)` is picking the  first candidate element always. We would like to know if we can use a comparator function to control the candidate element returned by `ranges_type.lower_type(Range(n))` . For example suppose we would only want a lower_bound answer with caseNumber 1 or case Number 10. Then we tried changing the class Range operator < to:

```
bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const{
    if ((mCaseNumber == 10 || mCaseNumber == 1) &&
    (rhs.mCaseNumber == 10 || rhs.mCaseNumber == 1)){
       return mHigh < rhs.mHigh;
     }
     else {
      return false;
     }
}
```

Unfortunately, this primitive operator did not function properly.
    We were wondering if it possible to change the comparator function so that std::lower_bound only returns a Range element with CaseNumber 10 or Case 1 but not does not return a Range element with case 15. Our original class Range is shown below.

```
class Range { 
     public:   
         explicit Range(int item){
            mLow = item;
            mHigh = item;
            mPtr  = 0;
            mMapPtr = 0;
            mStamp = 0;
            mCaseNumber = 100;
            mCurrentN = 0;
         }
         Range(int low, int high, char* ptr = 0,char* mapptr = 0, int stamp = 0, 
               int casenumber = 100, int currN = 0,int currMappedLength = 0){  
            mLow = low;
            mHigh = high;
            mPtr  = ptr;
            mMapPtr = mapptr;
                           mStamp = stamp;
            mCaseNumber = casenumber;
            mCurrentN = currN;
                           mMappedLength = currMappedLength;        
         }
         Range(void){  
            mLow = 0;
            mHigh = 0;
            mPtr  = 0;
            mMapPtr = 0;
                            mStamp = 0;
            mCaseNumber = 100;
            mCurrentN = 0;
         }

         Range(const Range& r):
            mLow(r.mLow),
            mHigh(r.mHigh),
            mPtr(r.mPtr),
            mMapPtr(r.mMapPtr),
            mStamp(r.mStamp),
            mCaseNumber(r.mCaseNumber),
            mCurrentN(r.mCurrentN),
                           mMappedLength(r.mMappedLength)
         {
         }

         ~Range(){
         }  


         bool operator==(const Range& rhs) const{
             return (mLow <= rhs.mLow && mHigh >= rhs.mHigh);
         }
         bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const{
                return mHigh < rhs.mHigh;
         } 
         int low() const { return mLow; }   
         int high() const { return mHigh; }
         char* getPtr() const { return mPtr; }
         char* getMapPtr() const { return mMapPtr; }
         int getStamp() const { return mStamp; }
         int getCaseNumber() const { return mCaseNumber; }
                 int getMappedLength() const { return mMappedLength; }
     private:   
         int mLow;   
         int mHigh; 
         char* mPtr;
         char* mMapPtr;
         int mStamp;
         int mCaseNumber;
         int mCurrentN;
         int mMappedLength;
}; // class Range
```

Comment: Have you tried passing a pointer to your comparator function in the constructor? See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/multiset/

Comment: @Dario_Ramos, Yes, we tried creating a comparator function to std::lower_bound(ranges_type.begin(),ranges_type.end(),Range(n),Comparator()). Alas, we are not stll getting the right answer(i.e. caseNumber = 10 or 1). Perhaps , our comparision functor is wrong. Do you have any ideas how the comparator functor should like? We are trying STL::multiset::equal_range. Do you think that will help? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I meant the multiset's constructor, not the iterator's. Anyway, did you check that your Comparator function is getting called (i.e. debugging)?

Comment: @Dario_Ramos, If we pass the comparison functor to the multiset's constructor then we end up ignoring the Range bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const{ return mHigh < rhs.mHigh;} shown above, We know from Stack Overflow that the a STL multiset constructor cannot have multiple comparison functions unlike Boost Multi-Index. We tried Boost MultiIndex but it runs slower than STL, for some reason. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Darip_Ramos, We checked and found that our Comparator function is getting called in the debugger. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [std::lower_bound's documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/), the comparison function you pass as the third argument is a:

> Comparison function object that,
>   taking two values of the same type
>   than those contained in the range,
>   returns true if the first argument
>   goes before the second argument in the
>   specific strict weak ordering it
>   defines, and false otherwise.

So, try something like this:

```
bool Range::CustomComparator( const Range& lhs, const Range& rhs ){//declare it static
    //Your logic here
}
```

And pass Range::CustomComparator to the lower_bound call

Comment: And make damn sure that it's still a Strict Weak Ordering.

Comment: @dario_ramos, Thank you for your answer. We are trying out std::equal_range because the STL::multiset<Range> multiset has multiple Range element candidate correspoding  to Range(n). How would your lower_bound comparator handle multiple candidates? Is it possible for you to show us the Custom Comparator would handle only case numbers 1 and 10 and not case 15? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, Thank you for your reply about strict weak ordering. Here is our comparator function:struct Comparator { int Offset; Comparator(int N){ Offset = N; } bool operator () ( const Range& d1, const Range& d2 ) const { if ((d1.getCaseNumber() == 10 || d1.getCaseNumber() == 1 ) && (d2.getCaseNumber() == 10 || d2.getCaseNumber() == 1){ return d1.high() <= d2.high() && ((d1.low() >= Offset && d1.high() > Offset) && (d2.low() >= Offset && d2.high() > Offset)); } else return false; } }; Do you think this is correct? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, I do not have time to analyse that for you.

Comment: @dario_ramos, We just tested your Range::CustomComparator function and found that it does not handle overlapping or duplicate ranges correctly. This is not caused by custom comparator. It is caused by the strict weak ordering requirement for STL lower_bound. Do you know which STL data structure and algorithm is best for handling overlapping and duplicate intervals? Thank you

Comment: Well, the function I wrote is missing its comparison logic (I left that up to you), which must satisfy a weak ordering. if you must keep your Ranges sorted, and Ranges can be repeated, I'd say your choice of multiset is alright. However, I'm not sure I understand something: When you create the multiset, and add Ranges to it, it sorts them according to Range::operator<, the one you defined. However, when you call std::lower_bound, you decide to use _another_ ordering criteria (Range::CustomComparator). That seems a little weird to me, shouldn't you use the same criterion for both?

Comment: @Frank That's a good question - much better than the one you started with. You might get a better response if you ask it as a new question.

Comment: @dario_ramos, We agree with you. The Range::operator < should be used for inserting , deleting  and searching such as lower bound. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: If that's the case, it's in Range::operator< where you should implement your custom sorting logic. And there's no need to pass any comparison function to std::lower_bound, it will use Range::operator<. About that logic, that is, the definition of Range::operator<, I can't get my head around it easily now, I'll take a closer look when I get home

Comment: @dario_ramos. I just accepted your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frank: Thank you, sorry I couldn't help you better. Did you use the solution described in my answer, or did you change your implementation of Range::operator<? In the latter case, I should edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @dario_ramos, Thank you for reply. We changed the implementation of the comparator functor class used in the STL constructor. Thank you.